# Why paired comment can't be placed inside a string in c++?

Tags: c++

Normally anything inside `/*` and `*/` is considered as a comment.

But the statement,
`std::cout << "not-a-comment /* comment */";`
prints `not-a-comment /* comment */` instead of `not-a-comment`.

Why does this happen? Are there any other places in c++ where I can't use comments?

Comment: As for the "why", the simple answer is that it follows the definition of the C++ language.

Comment: You can write it like `"not-a-comment "/* comment */""`

Comment: What's wrong with `std::cout << "not-a-comment";  /* comment */`??

Comment: I couldn't understand why `std::cout << "not-a-comment /* comment */";` didn't work. @haccks

Comment: It did work, @Shobith. However, your expectations are flawed concerning what "works" means.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a consequence of the maximum munch principle. It's a lexing rule that the C++ language follows. When processing a source file, translation is divided into (logical) phases. During phase 3, we get preprocsessing tokens:

> **[lex.phases]**
>
> [1.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/lex#phases-1.3) The source file is decomposed into preprocessing tokens and
>   sequences of white-space characters (including comments). A source
>   file shall not end in a partial preprocessing token or in a partial
>   comment. Each comment is replaced by one space character. New-line
>   characters are retained.

Turning comments into white space pp-tokens is done at the same phase. Now a string literal is a pp-token:

> **[lex.pptoken]**
>
> ```
> preprocessing-token:
>   header-name
>   identifier
>   pp-number
>   character-literal
>   user-defined-character-literal
>   string-literal
>   user-defined-string-literal
>   preprocessing-op-or-punc
>   each non-white-space character that cannot be one of the above
> ```

As are other literals. And the maximum munch principle, tells us that:

> [3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/lex.pptoken#3) If the input stream has been parsed into preprocessing tokens up to a
>   given character:
>
> - Otherwise, the next preprocessing token is the longest sequence of characters that could constitute a preprocessing token, even if that
>     would cause further lexical analysis to fail, except that a
>     header-name is only formed within a #include directive.

So because preprocessing found the opening `"`, it must keep looking for the longest sequence of characters that will make a valid pp-token (in this case, the token is a string literal). This sequence ends at the closing `"`. That's why it can't stop and handle the comment, because it is obligated to consume up to the closing quotation mark.

Following these rules you can pin-point the places where comments will not be handled by the pre-processor as comments.

Answer (score 4):

> Why does this happen?

Because the comment becomes part of the string literal (eveything between the `""` double quotes).

> Are there any other places in c++ where I can't use comments?

Yes, the same applies for character literals (using `''` single quotes).

---

You can think of it like single and double quotes have *higher precedence* before the comment delimiters `/**/`.